# JQuery selector based on ID in Coffee Script

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have the following callback (Coffee Script):

`$(document).on 'ajax:success', 'a.add_to_cart', (status, data, xhr)->`

`a.add_to_cart` is the selector for a `link_to` with `class=add_to_cart`.

What would be the selector for a `button_to` (based on its id)?

Comment: That does not seem to work.

Comment: Then I suggest updating the question with a [mcve], as it's not clear what you're looking for if it's not an ID selector.

Answer (score 0):

An ID is supposed to be assigned to one element on a page only. If you give it an id of `foo`, then you could reference using the `#foo` jquery selector since `#` means id.

Anyway, a `button_to` generates a `<button>`, and you can always look at the generated HTML using your browser dev tool inspector.